# Removing default user data

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I saw a post ages ago about how to remove the default user data that comes with the preview of Ubuntu touch and now I can find it. I just want my table to look like i've installed Ubuntu touch from fresh so I can add my own user account and info.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

To remove **sample contacts**: Run

```
manage-address-books.py delete
```

in a shell.

Edit /etc/[phone|tablet]-services and

```
remove manage-address-books.py
```

To remove **sample video and music lenses**: Run

```
rm /usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.canonical.Unity.Lens.MockMusic.service
rm /usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.canonical.Unity.Lens.MockVideos.service
```

To remove **pictures from gallery**: Run

```
rm /home/phablet/Pictures/*
```

To remove **sample messages in messaging menu**:

Edit /etc/[phone|tablet]-services and remove chewie_messaging_populate_menu

[(source)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes)